# Android FTS3 query multiple tables No such table

Tags: android-sqlite

I am trying to search text from multiple tables using FTS3 in android sqlite.

But its giving NO SUCH TABLE exception. tables are creating and tried changing database name and version.But it didnt work.

Could any one help. wts causing the issue.??

This is my query statement :

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables("FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE,FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE_NEW");
    builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);
    Cursor cursor = builder.query(
            mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(), columns, selection,
            selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

and the error i m getting is ...

08-01 04:43:58.412: W/SuggestionsAdapter(5069): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, suggest_text_1, suggest_text_2, suggest_text_1, suggest_text_2, suggest_intent_data_id FROM FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE,FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE_NEW WHERE (suggest_text_1 MATCH ?)

Comment: please post you query statement and error which you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

```
("FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE","FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE_NEW")
```

it should be like this or if these are constant variables than no need double quotes, simply write

```
(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE,FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE_NEW)
```

and use column name with Table Name followed by dot followed by column name.

or I suggest use simple query rather than using SQLiteQueryBuilder.